# How to set icon size in Outlook 2010 add in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I develope an outlook 2010 add-in, 
I have    Office.CommandBars cmdBars that holds    Office.CommandBarButton,
I set the    buttonTemp_Dial.Style = Office.MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonIconAndCaption
and    buttonTemp_Dial.Picture have a reference to icon pic.
The icon in add in is small how can I change it to big Icon?

the add-in is in separate tab in Outlook, is there a way to put the add in to the "Home" tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the old CommandBars based API, your button will appear on the Addins tab, which is probably not something that you want.

Your add-in (on the low level) needs to implement the IRibbonExtensibility interface and return your customization as XML - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb226712(v=office.12).aspx